# how get list of all the possible combinations of 4 digit numbers whose individual digit sum is 13 and last digit is 5 in that number

Tags: python, python-3.x

How get all the possible combinations of 4 digit numbers whose individual digit sum is 13 and last digit is 5 in that number?

I am trying it in python as:

```
nmz = []
for i in range(1000,10000):
    if ((sum(int(j) for j in str(i))==13) & (i % 10)):
        nmz = nmz.append(i)
        return(nmz)
    else:
        continue
```

I am getting errors and not able to get expected output:

```
nmz = [1165,    1345,   1435,   1615,   1705,   2245,   2425,   3055 ..... ]
```

errors are:

1. no output as expected
2. SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: `nmz = [i for i in range(1000, 10000) if sum(int(j) for j in str(i)) == 13 and str(i)[-1] == '5']` this should work

Comment: To start, you use `return(nmz)` in what looks like a top level bock of code. This statement if used must be within a function.. You can probably just take it out. The else and continue are also not needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no point in starting the range at 1000 because it doesn't fulfil the significant criterion that the number should end with 5. So, start at 1005 and increment by 10. Therefore:

```
mylist = []
for i in range(1_005, 10_000, 10):
    if sum(int(d) for d in str(i)) == 13:
        mylist.append(i)

print(mylist)
```

**Output:**

```
[1075, 1165, 1255, 1345, 1435, 1525, 1615, 1705, 2065, 2155, 2245, 2335, 2425, 2515, 2605, 3055, 3145, 3235, 3325, 3415, 3505, 4045, 4135, 4225, 4315, 4405, 5035, 5125, 5215, 5305, 6025, 6115, 6205, 7015, 7105, 8005]
```

Answer (score 4):

Faster alternative using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which doesn't require the `int` -> `str` conversion:

```py
from itertools import product

[sum(a*10**b for a,b in zip(reversed(i), range(len(i))))  # decimal integer from individual integers
 for i in product(range(1,10), range(10), range(10), [5]) # all combinations
 if sum(i)==13]                                           # condition to keep
```

output:

```
[1075, 1165, 1255, 1345, 1435, 1525, 1615, 1705, 2065, 2155, 2245, 2335, 2425, 2515, 2605, 3055, 3145, 3235, 3325, 3415, 3505, 4045, 4135, 4225, 4315, 4405, 5035, 5125, 5215, 5305, 6025, 6115, 6205, 7015, 7105, 8005]
```

Version for any number of digits:

```py
from itertools import product

DIGITS = 4

[sum(a*10**b for a,b in zip(reversed(i), range(len(i))))
 for i in product(range(1,10), *([range(10)]*(DIGITS-2)), [5])
 if sum(i)==13]
```

This answer and particularly the suggestion in the comments by @keyllbundy are much faster than other currently posted answers and these techniques of leveraging `itertools` should be understood by all python users. If you want to see how much faster they are, you can use the `timeit` module like:

```py
import timeit

setup = """
import itertools

def olvin_roght():
    mylist = []
    for i in range(1_005, 10_000, 10):
        if sum(int(d) for d in str(i)) == 13:
            mylist.append(i)
    return mylist

def jonsg():
    return [10*i+5 for i in range(100, 1000) if sum(int(j) for j in str(i)) == 8]

def mozway():
    DIGITS = 4
    return [
        sum(a*10**b for a,b in zip(reversed(i), range(len(i))))
        for i in itertools.product(range(1,10), *([range(10)]*(DIGITS-2)), [5])
        if sum(i)==13
    ] 

def kelly_bundy():
    return [(1+a) * 1000 + (b-a) * 100 + (7-b) * 10 + 5
            for a, b in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(8), 2)]
"""
print(f"olvin_roght: {timeit.timeit('olvin_roght()', setup=setup, number=10_000)}")
print(f"jonsg: {timeit.timeit('jonsg()', setup=setup, number=10_000)}")
print(f"mozway: {timeit.timeit('mozway()', setup=setup, number=10_000)}")
print(f"kelly_bundy: {timeit.timeit('kelly_bundy()', setup=setup, number=10_000)}")
```

This should show you results like:

```
olvin_roght: 8.36
jonsg: 7.19
mozway: 1.70
kelly_bundy: 0.08
```

Comment: @Kelly 5 times faster

Comment: I just ran the various codes in jupyter with `%%timeit`

Comment: How about `[a * 1000 + b * 100 + (8-a-b) * 10 + 5
       for a in range(1, 9)
       for b in range(9 - a)]`?

Comment: Also faster (and generalizable) might be `[(1+a) * 1000 + (b-a) * 100 + (7-b) * 10 + 5
       for a, b in combinations_with_replacement(range(8), 2)]`.

Comment: @Kelly nice, ~ 20x faster (expected as you have one less level of combination)

Comment: From a performance perspective, this is an important answer as it contains two alternatives that are **much** faster. One is two orders of magnitude faster than the currently accepted answer. I am going to add timeit code for others to see.  Feel free to undo my edit if you feel it does not improve the answer.

Comment: @mozway Yes, one less level, and also no filtering/waste, just producing exactly what's needed.

Comment: Please, change `olvin_roght` to `fake_olvin_roght` :D

Comment: @Olvin Roght Did they change your code? Looks the same to me.

Comment: @KellyBundy, that's actually not my code. I am another user at all. [Somebody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17580381/olvin-roght) created a profile using my name. 10 mins ago I've been confused af when I saw that 5 mins ago I left a comment  on question which I'd just opened. That's ridiculous :D

Comment: Hmm, I just realized my combinations_with_replacement isn't quite as generalizable as I thought. I can make it support any number of digits, but not any sum. The way it works is that of the desired digit sum 13, fixed 5 goes to the last digit, a *minimum* of 1 goes to the first digit, and the remaining 7 are distributed to the first three digits. And I choose two split points to split the 7 into three parts, one for each of those three digits. But that doesn't upper-bound how much gets distributed to each digit.

Comment: @Olvin Roght Ah, haha :-) I had actually noticed their new profile image next to the old name, but didn't realize what was going on. How likely is it that it's their real name?

Comment: @KellyBundy, his(her) nickname was "JCaesar", it have been changed recently.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly alternate approach would be to reframe the questions from:

> Get a list of all the possible combinations of 4 digit numbers whose
> individual digits sum to 13 and last digit is 5

as:

> Get all 3 digit numbers whose sum is 8.

Then we can do:

```py
results = [i*10+5 for i in range(100, 1000) if sum(int(j) for j in str(i)) == 8]
```

or formatted a bit as:

```py
results = [
    i * 10 + 5
    for i
    in range(100, 1000)
    if 8 == sum(
            int(j)
            for j
            in str(i)
        )
]
```

Also giving us:

```
[1075, 1165, 1255, 1345, 1435, 1525, 1615, 1705, 2065, 2155, 2245, 2335, 2425, 2515, 2605, 3055, 3145, 3235, 3325, 3415, 3505, 4045, 4135, 4225, 4315, 4405, 5035, 5125, 5215, 5305, 6025, 6115, 6205, 7015, 7105, 8005]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find all of the answers with:

```py
nums = []
for i in range(1000,10000):
    sumi = (sum([int(j) for j in str(i)])) # sum of i digits
    i_l = i % 10 # i last digit
    if i_l == 5 and sumi == 13:
        nums.append(i)

print (nums)
```